# Java Class does nothing

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, system.out

I want to print an 2 dimensional double Array to the console.

```
  public class arrayprinter {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] multi = new double[][]{
              { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
              { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4},
              { 1.2, 3.2},
              { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
            };
        print(multi);
    }
    private static void print(double[][] e){
        for(int i=0; i>e.length;i++) {
            print(e[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void print(double[] e) {
        for(int i=0; i>e.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(e[i]);     }
    }
  }
```

When i click the play button in eclipse there is only: `<terminated>...`and no printed array in the console. Can someone say me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Next times, just try to debug this. Print message here and there or use debugger. You would a found that the loop was wrong.

Comment: The litlle bug icon did not found this. Maybe I have to have look at the debugger manual.

Comment: Yes you should read it. The debugger is not automatic, this is a runtime where you can add some break point. Those will stop the program when it read a specific line giving you the opportunities to check the value of your variable/instance.

Comment: Bug icon?  You're depending on the IDE too much.  Thinking for yourself has to come first.

Comment: There's no bug in this code from the IDE's point of view: it's valid Java, and it will compile and execute it dutifully. The bug is in the difference between what you intended and what you actually wrote, which the IDE can't possibly know.

Comment: @Andy Turner It is a logical mistake no Syntax. I think bug is also logical.

Comment: @Colin right. But how can your IDE show a "bug icon" if you made a logical error?

Comment: @Andy Turner It is the debug mode Icon and it has the shape of a bug. It is always there

Comment: @Colin you know that "debug" doesn't actually find bugs for you, right? *You* have to find them; it just helps you to do so.

Comment: @Andy Turner but I could do line by line. But the Debugger rushed through the program code so I didn't know what was wrong. As I said I have to have a look at the debugger manual next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program never reaches the line which prints. You start at `i=0` and increment it while it's bigger that `e.length`, but it never is, because the loop exists at the first run (`i = 0` and `0` is not bigger than `e.length` so it exists the loop) 
use these:

```
private static void print(double[][] e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        print(e[i]);
    }
}

public static void print(double[] e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(e[i]);
    }
}
```

I replaced the `>` with `<` in the loop.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you too

Comment: @Colin if you accept the answer, mark it as accepted (v symbol under answer score)

Comment: I have to wait 8 minutes then I can accept

Comment: @Colin oh. Well ok (I suppose you can upvote useful answers)

Comment: I cant. I am missing 1 rep point.

Comment: @Colin The minimum is 15, not 20

Comment: It is changing all the time. Now I can

Comment: And I suppose you can stop claiming reps ;)

Comment: @AxelH - I now it's not such a good thing, but It really helps me when I see that my answer is correct (to be honest, I'm not a very good programmer). And also I made a bet with my brother who can get more points in a month... :P

Comment: Indeed, this is not good ! Stackoverflow is not a game ... don't spam to beat your brother. I might check your answers now ;)

Comment: @AxelH ohhhh boy. o.o

Answer (score 6):

You want to do

```
i < e.length
```

not "`i>e.length`".

Comment: Oh I am embarrassed now. You are right that fixed my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison i>e.length is wrong it should be i < e.length, see code below

```
private static void print(double[][] e){
    for(int i=0; i<e.length;i++) {
        print(e[i]);
    }
}
public static void print(double[] e) {
    for(int i=0; i<e.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(e[i]);     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing two methods you can also use a one liner like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       double[][] multi = new double[][]{
          { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
          { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4},
          { 1.2, 3.2},
          { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
        };
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(multi));
    }
```

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind.